# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString') on Inertia

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, inertiajs

I am trying to implement a searchable input. But getting `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')` on vue.

Here is my controller function :

`ArticleController.php`

```
public function create(Request $request)
    {
        return Inertia::render(
            'Article/New',
            [
                'categories' => Category::when($request->cateQuery, function ($query, $cateQuery) {
                    echo $query->get();
                    $query->where('name', 'ILIKE', '%' . $cateQuery . '%');
                }),
            ]
        );
    }
```

**without the `echo` statement above, it doesn't return anything.**

`web.php`

```
Route::resource('articles', ArticleController::class)
    ->only(['index', 'create', 'store'])
    ->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);
```

Search Input in `New.vue`

```
<input
                    type="text"
                    v-model="cateQuery"
                    @keyup="searchCategory"
                    placeholder="search.."
                    class="search-bar"
/>
```

and script in 'New.vue'

```
<script>
import _ from "lodash";
import AuthenticatedLayout from "@/Layouts/AuthenticatedLayout.vue";
export default {
    components: {
        AuthenticatedLayout,
    },
    props: {
        categories: Object,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            cateQuery: "",
        };
    },
    methods: {
        searchCategory:function () {
            this.$inertia.get(
                route("articles.create", { cateQuery: this.cateQuery })
            );
        }
    },
};
</script>
```

and on input i am getting

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')
    at u (url.ts:6:23)
    at router.ts:318:27
```

`const responseUrl = hrefToUrl(pageResponse.url)` in **Router.ts** throws the error.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: This may have nothing to do with the question but you have a typo in your controller. Its 'LIKE' not 'ILIKE' maybe that is causing a background issue

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL and `ILIKE` is a valid operator https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/postgresql-ilike-operator/